# Javascript pass event to debounce function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a function that fetches more fields from an api when an onPopUpScroll event is triggered. I need to pass an event object to the lodash debounce function but it doesnt work I get an error. This is what I first had:

```
function loadMoreUsers = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    const {target} = e;

    // fetch data from api and also use target properties 
} 

const loadMore = debounce(loadMoreUsers, 3000);  // used lodash debounce


// The component
<Select onPopupScroll={loadMore}>
    // Options
</Select>
```

I get this error:

```
This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
```

It is pointing to line const {target} = e. I think it might be because debounce has its own event object that its passing but I need to pass the event object from the select component thru the debounce function

Comment: This is React, right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500255/warning-this-synthetic-event-is-reused-for-performance-reasons-happening-with

Comment: Yes this is react, I couldnt find a solution on that page as I already have `e.persist()` right before I access the event.

Comment: And where is `debounce` coming from? Is it from lodash?

Comment: Yes debounce from lodash