# Using Onchange in JSX (React)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, onchange

I'm implementing contact-form functionality into a bigger project. The form works fine separately, though it's written in JS (you can find it [here](https://github.com/hpols/ContactForm-With-Recaptcha/blob/main/nodemailer-form/src/App.js). My bigger project is however, set up in JSX, where I get an error as soon as I type into an input-field. The error points at line 22 of the code, saying the respective field is null. When I log the value it is, indeed, not retrieving anything from what has been added. Here is the code snippet of where it happens:

```
const [mailerState, setMailerState] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
  });

  const captchaRef = useRef(null);
  
  function handleStateChange(e) {
    setMailerState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value, <<<< The error codes points here >>>>
    }));
    console.log(mailerState);
  }
```

my input fields look like this:

```
<input
           placeholder="Name"
           onChange={handleStateChange}
           name="name"
           value={mailerState.name}
         />
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    at Kontakt.jsx:22:1
    at basicStateReducer (react-dom.development.js:15013:1)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:15135:1)
    at updateState (react-dom.development.js:15237:1)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:15949:1)
    at useState (react.development.js:1497:1)
    at Kontakt (Kontakt.jsx:11:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18610:1)
```

I suspect JSX wants this handled a little differently. I've also tried onBlur but get the same results. I'm still learning the finer details of using JSX, so would appreciate any help and pointers. Many thanks!

---

I've whittled it down to a skeleton for GitHub. The issue still happens for me, but bare in mind the message will not send like this. The full Kontakt.jsx is [here](https://github.com/hpols/ReactSample/blob/main/src/components/Kontakt.jsx), and the rest of the React-setup is along with it.

Comment: your code seems like it should work. can you provide a [mre] maybe on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: I try to reproduce it and the above code is working fine please add more code or host your project code if possible.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(e)` in that function?

Comment: @RonnyEfronny the console.log I do at the end of the `handleStateChang` function results in `{name: '', email: '', message: ''}`. To me, this means it's not registering the changes. Indeed the page goes blank within a second or two of typing into a field.

Comment: That's not what I asked. State changes only happen when the scope that called them ends, by default. Put your `console.log` outside of `handleStateChange` to see the change on re-render. What I ask is that you `console.log` the `e` to see what is actually in it.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny, ah sorry. There are so many "e"s running around I wasn't quite following. I'm adding the output to the original question as it's quite a lot …

Comment: Still not what I'm looking for. You function `handleStateChange` receives `e` (for `event`). Print this `e` to see if the field that you're trying to get (which is crashing the app) exists.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny, caught that just now (I was a little too fast when adjusting the code). See above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247792/discussion-between-ronny-efronny-and-atschpe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the example and discussing the output it seems the issue stems from the fact that you're using React and are getting a synthetic event which sometimes has an odd behavior.

I am by no means an expert, but I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56629758/19420291) is all you need to know in order to get this code to work properly.
Alternatively as per the warning you get, you could try to call `e.persist()`, though I am not sure if this could cause other issues.

Should probably also [read up on synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) to understand what's going on.