# This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this Form.List component of antd library in react,when i select any options in salesman, i get so many warning stating that:

> index.js:1 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `pageX` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

This is the code:

```
<Form.List name="salesmans" initialValue={personList}>
    {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
      const newfields = fields.filter(
        (field) => field.name !== '0'
      )
      return (
        <>
          {newfields.map((field, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <Col md={10}>
                <AutoFieldComponent
                  name={[field.name, 'salesperson']}
                  label={`Salesman ${index + 1}`}
                  options={salesOptions}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: index === 0,
                      message: 'Please select Salesman',
                    },
                  ]}
                  filterOption={(input, option) => {
                    return option?.label
                      ?.toLowerCase()
                      .includes(input?.toLowerCase())
                  }}
                  existingValue={
                    projectData?.salesPersons[field?.name]
                  }
                  placeholder={`select salesman ${index + 1}`}
                  type="text"
                  values={0}
                />
              </Col>
              <div className="detete-icon">
                <Button
                  title={'Delete Salesman'}
                  onClick={() => {
                    remove(field.name)
                  }}
                  disabled={index === 0}
                  icon={<DeleteIcon />}
                />
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
          <Col md={12} className="sales-btn">
            <Button
              onClick={add}
              type="link"
              className="add-package"
              label="Add another salesman"
              icon={<AddPackage />}
            />
          </Col>
        </>
      )
    }}
  </Form.List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with handling events.
OnClick function of the delete button seems fine, but you should check the `add()` handler.

Probably you are trying to access events properties in asynchronous function (example : you are trying to set a state)

You need to assign variables from the event at the beginning of the `add()` handler so you can use them later

[Here's the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500255/warning-this-synthetic-event-is-reused-for-performance-reasons-happening-with)

EDIT:

Use `onClick={() => add()}` like this and not like this `onClick={add}` because the types of onClick() and add() function don't match. You can check add() type [in the Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/#operation)

Comment: but add handler is provided by antd , i don't have code for add function, what should i do?

Comment: I have edited the answer, i think this will work now